# How to get Referrer in react application

Tags: javascript, reactjs, referrer

I need to get referrer domain in my react application, Let say if I click my url from gmail I need the referrer to be https://mail.google.com.

```
useEffect(() => {
  setReferrer(document.referrer)
}, []);
```

But it getting the my same domain instead of the Referrer url. Any help please?

Comment: Check the `<a>` on the email. Does the link have `rel="noreferrer`?

Comment: No there is not rel property in that <a> tag.

Comment: Then I'd check if you're getting the `Referrer-Policy` header on mail.google.com, or if there's a `<meta name="referrer" ...>` tag in the HTML. All in all, if you're interested in tracing where people are coming from and you control the links that are sent, [I'd add a query parameter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTM_parameters) to your links where you specify the ID of where you've sent it or something like that.

Comment: ^^ I agree -- Not only is "referrer" difficult to rely on ..  It can also be spoofed to "look like" it comes from anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

go to /index.html if it's a CRA project and juste add

```
<meta name="referrer" content="no-referrer">
```

in the head tag